# Should a Statement of Purpose for a PhD program concentrate on facts or emotions?

Tags: application, statement-of-purpose

I am applying for Ph.D. programs in pure mathematics. One of the confusions I have about writing a Statement of Purpose is whether I should concentrate on the things I did (mentioning facts: REUs, Courses, Talks, Putnam exam, Teaching) or whether I should be more poetic and write about why am I a person who wants to do research, why am I capable of doing it, and why do I love mathematics. If I have mentioned some information already in one of the parts of my application, is it bad if I write about it again in my Statement of Purpose?

Comment: Facts, facts, facts. But the things you've already done should not be the main focus. It's a statement of _purpose_, so you should describe what area(s) you want to do research in, why school X is a good place to do that, and why your background prepares you for success in the program.

Comment: there are many good questions already about this, duplicate.

Comment: @user4050 Could you give me some references?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing research ideas to include in a statement of purpose](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1529/choosing-research-ideas-to-include-in-a-statement-of-purpose)

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/36725/20058

Comment: In your statement of purpose you may fantasize about what you'd like to do.  (Other parts of your application will document what you've accomplished.)  You may use 10 - 20% of your essay to cover motivation if you wish.